# Color names allowed in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, colors, html-lists

I know and use a few color names like 'white', 'blue', 'red', is there a complete list of colors allowed in HTML/CSS ?

Comment: erm, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=css+colors&l=1

Comment: @nimbuz, why did you accept a wrong answer? that doesn't make the quality of SO better, if you just accept whatever answer.

Comment: All answers are more or less similar.

Comment: my answer says essentially the same thing as the one that is selected as the answer and was up a few minutes before the one selected as answer.... not only that but someone voted it down. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a plethora of colors listed at http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_colornames.asp. There's also a cautionary note at the bottom:

> Note: The names above are not a part of the W3C web standard.
>
> The W3C HTML and CSS standards have listed only 16 valid color names:
>   aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow.
>
> If you want valid HTML or CSS use the HEX values instead.

Comment: This is no longer entirely true: HTML4 only lists 16 colors, but CSS3 lists a total of 147 valid color names—the same ones in SVG (which are mostly based on X11).  Longer answer in a bit since I can’t deal with the return key in comments.

Answer (score 8):

[CSS3-color](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color) has the complete 'Extended color keywords' list.

Answer (score 2):

The CSS Color Module Level 3, which is a full W3C Recommendation and therefore supersedes CSS2 where they conflict, lists the 16 HTML4 keywords as [“Basic color keywords”](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4) and the 147 SVG keywords as [“Extended color keywords”](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color)—the latter set of 147 being a superset of the basic 16, since they’re all included.

So the answer to your question is 147 names long, not 16; W3Schools, not surprisingly, has it wrong.  There are also WAY more keywords actually recognized by browsers, but they’re not “allowed” in a legalistic sense even if they are in a practical sense.  As a result, there might be slight differences between browsers when handling those keywords, since they haven’t been precisely defined in a specification.

(P.S. If you’re interested in a sortable table of all 147 extended keywords and their various numeric equivalents, I recently published one on [my site](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/colors/) along with some visualizations of the basic and extended keywords sets: [color wheel](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/colors/hsl-16.html) and [distribution chart](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/colors/hsl-147.html).)

(P.P.S. The CSS3 Colors module was not a full Recommendation in 2009.)

Answer (score 1):

> The W3C HTML and CSS standards have listed only 16 valid color names:
>   aqua, black, blue, fuchsia, gray, green, lime, maroon, navy, olive, purple, red, silver, teal, white, and yellow.

From this site:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_colornames.asp

Comment: Umm.... why did this get voted down? My response was up before the one selected as the answer.

Comment: Probably because you referenced w3schools.com, which is [horribly out of date and often incorrect](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: Which was the same website referenced by the answer..... so what is your point exactly?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 17 "standard" colors, according to W3 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#color-units

In addition, there are some built-in names for system colors: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#system-colors

This 2nd set is deprecated in CSS3.